# Writing migration for Smart Contract in Solidity

Tags: node.js, migration, solidity, contract

I'm trying to write a migration for some smart contracts and this error comes up in the compiler.

```
Error:   Deployment Failed 

"MasterChefV2" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 2 expected 5!.
```

Here is my migration js:

```
const Masterchef = artifacts.require('MasterChefV2.sol');
const EGG = artifacts.require('EggToken.sol');
const Timelock = artifacts.require('Timelock.sol');

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Masterchef, EGG, Timelock);
  };
```

and this is the MasterChefV2 constructor

```
constructor(
        EggToken _egg,
        address _devaddr,
        address _feeAddress,
        uint256 _eggPerBlock,
        uint256 _startBlock
    ) public {
        egg = _egg;
      `enter code here`     devaddr = _devaddr;
            feeAddress = _feeAddress;
            eggPerBlock = _eggPerBlock;
            startBlock = _startBlock;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's simply because during the deployement you give only 2 parameters. And obviously 5 are needed.

Migration file only find the 2 follow parameters :

- EGGToken .sol
- Your dev address (from where you call the deployement)

You need to add manually the 3 others :

- Start block
- Fee address
- EGG per block